# ProcessBuilder - array parameter

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am running an .exe from a Java application using `ProcessBuilder`. I can run the .exe, and can pass it scalar arguments, but I was wondering how to pass in an array as a parameter?

My code looks like:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder(path, 
    Integer.toString(firstParam), 
    "where i want array to be").
    start();
```

Comment: How does the the external program expect the array argument to be formatted? Delimited by commas?

Comment: Still not sure of the exact form of the array required (as queried by @Slaw). But general tips: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Comment: Yes, the delimiter is a comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `ProcessBuilder` each element in the command is a separate argument.

```
String[] array = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};
String arg = String.join(",", array);
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("path/to/command.exe", "--argument-name", arg)
            .inheritIO() // replace with your own IO handling if needed
            .start();
```

I don't believe you have to worry with surrounding `arg` in quotes since `ProcessBuilder` will take care of sending it as a single argument for you.

The above should be equivalent to this command line:

```
path/to/command.exe --argument-name "Item 1,Item 2,Item 3"
```

Comment: Thanks. Out of interest, if I had an array containing further arrays, would I want to do create a string for each sub-array like above and then craft them together like: "\"" + array_one + "\",\"" + array_two + "\",\"" + ...